# ProgressBar Background doesn't show on android 5.1 and above

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I'm trying to fix an issue appearing only on android 5.1 and above regarding a circular ProgressBar: the background property works perfectly on android 5.0 but it isn't shown in other versions. Do you know why it could happen?
Here is my code:

pbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@android:id/background">
     <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
        <solid android:color="#A6A6A6"/>
     </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
     <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:thicknessRatio="7.0">
        <solid android:color="#3CECDE"/>
     </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relative_pbram"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp">
   <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/pb_ram"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:progress="0"
        android:max="100"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:rotationY="180"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/pbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the progressbar on android 7.0 and 5.0 respectively

[image: Android 7.0][image: Android 5.0]

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `android:useLevel="false"` in your first shape (background). Your second shape is set correct `android:useLevel="true"`.

Nexus 5X Android 7.1

[image]